# i18 support for native languages

Tags: internationalization, plone

In South Africa we have 11 official languages:

```
af = Afrikaans
en = English
nr = Ndebele
nso = Pedi / Nothern Sotho
ss = Swati
st = South Sotho
tn = Tswana
ts = Tsonga
ve = Venda
xh = Xhosa
zu = Zulu
```

To what extent does Plone support the languages mentioned?

Answer (score 6):

You may find Plone's existing translations at: https://github.com/collective/plone.app.locales/tree/master/plone/app/locales/locales

Of those on your list, in a quick review I only saw English and Afrikaans. There are several active South African Plone Developers (ZA was the site of a recent sprint), and you might want to see if there are possibilities for collaborative work on other translations. The Plone SA Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/plonesa